# Передача значений checkbox в скрипт

Tags: php, html, form, checkbox

Есть чеки в форме которые формируется при загрузке(на php)

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="2"name="bonus[1]" checked>
<label>1</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="bonus[2]" checked>
<label>2</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="24"  name="bonus[3]" checked>
<label id="fm-16" for="fm-17">3</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="25"  name="bonus[4]" checked>
<label>4</label>
```

по нажатию на саб обрабатывается в скрипте и потом выводит данные снова на эту же страницу.
код обрабывающий чеки

```js
for ($i = 1; $i < count($list_of_bonus) + 1; $i++) {
  echo $text = 'bonus['.$i']';
  if (isset($_POST[$text])) {
    echo "зашел";
  }
}
```

однако он не обрабатывает.что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имя чекбоксам задайте одинаковое и оформите их как массив

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2"name="bonus[]" checked>
<label>1</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="bonus[]" checked>
<label>2</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="24"  name="bonus[]" checked>
<label id="fm-16" for="fm-17">3</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="25"  name="bonus[]" checked>
<label>4</label>
```

PHP:

```
$list_of_bonus = $_POST['bonus']; //массив переданных значений
for ($i = 1; $i < count($list_of_bonus) + 1; $i++) {
  $text = 'bonus['.$i.']';  // тут точечку забыли
  echo $text;
  if (isset($_POST[$text])) {
    echo "зашел";
  }
}
```